# Removing python3.5 broke Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have purged python3.5 and its dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04, wanting to use 3.7 instead. Now, upon logging in, I have no access to anything, not even a terminal. How can I fix this?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & release details, but `python` is rather critical for many Ubuntu tools (including a `gnome-terminal`), so I'd login to a text terminal and reverse whatever you did.  You'll find many auto tools (`apt`, `apt-get`) may not work until python3 is restored to normal, but `dpkg` and like core tools will still work so it'll be more manual.  Reversing your changes is easiest, be it restore a backup, or using history & `apt` logs, but as we don't know what you did, you'll have the best clue.

Comment: Thank you guiverc. But how can I even log into terminal? This machine dual boots, Linux and Windows. Upon launching the computer, I can only select Linux or Windows. And once logged into Ubuntu, I have access to absolutely nothing. I am on Version 16.04.

Comment: Key is you need `python -V; python3 -V` to report correct values for your release.  Once you've `python3-minimal` installed again (as long as it's not interfered with by any changes you made), the rest will be easy.  Text terminals are **not** impacted by python changes (unless you've added python specific commands in login scripts).

Comment: I have only executed the following: sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3.5 And now I cannot access anything.

Comment: Login to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4) and restore python, or at minimum `python3-minimal` (minimum subset required).  You'll have to avoid any tools that need python (ie. GUI, `apt` & like front-end user tools) & stick to basic tools (text terminal, `dpkg` etc are coded in C, user-geared tools are often python).  Download using `wget` & use `dpkg -i` to install given you removed access to `apt-get` being usable I bet..

Comment: Thank you again guiverc. Is there a way to reverse the exact command that I have executed: sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3.5

Comment: Normally `apt-get purge` would be reversed by `apt-get install`, however you need to fix the python issue before `apt-get` will work... thus using the lower-level tools; `apt-get` is a front-end for, ie. `wget` & `dpkg` as I've already said..  the `python3-minimal` is the core package you'll need to get re-installed, then you'll find you can use higher-level tools like `apt-get` again making it easier

Comment: Thank you for your time and help guiverc.

Comment: Thank you again a million times guiverc. I was able to recover my installation.